# Issues with DOM API in Edge

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I wrote a chat app using websockets in Javascript.  I expected this to not be fully supported cross-browser.  However, I have run into an issue which seems to be caused by a difference in DOM manipulation API between Chrome/Firefox and Edge.  My app works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but errors in Edge.

Example HTML template from html file:

```
<template id ="message-template">
    <li class="media" style="margin-top:0px;">
        <div class="media-body">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                    <img class="media-object img-circle " src="" />
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <span id='message-body'> </span>
                    <br />
                    <small class="text-muted" id="message-user"></small>
                    <hr />
                </div>            
        </div>
    </li>
</template>
```

Example Javascript from js file manipulating and posting this template:

```
function addMessage(message){
    let date = new Date();
    let mtpl = document.getElementById('message-template').content.cloneNode(true);
    mtpl.getElementById('message-body').innerHTML = message.message;
    mtpl.getElementById('message-user').innerHTML = `${message.client} | ${date.toString()}`;
    messages.appendChild(mtpl);
    //Scroll down on overflow
    messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
}
```

The Error thrown by Edge is:
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementById'

Pointing to the line:

```
mtpl.getElementById('message-body').innerHTML = message.message;
```

I looked up the DOM API from Microsoft, and it appears that document.getElementById returns an IHTMLElement, which apparently does not have a getElementById method... so, my question is:

**How can I change my code to work on Edge?** 
(Ideally, I would like to be able to do this without jQuery, but if it's not possible, please let me know)

Note: I don't care about IE, as this is a personal project rather than commercial.  A lot of my code is written in ES6, which doesn't work in IE anyways.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just have `document.getElementById('message-body');`?

Comment: Yeah, messages.appendChild(mtpl) adds the new message to the chatbox.  If I use document.getElementById('message-body'), it would select the first message in the chatbox.

Comment: Are you saying that you have multiple elements with the same `id`?

Comment: Yes, the code quoted above injects a clone of the template.  The template has elements with id's, so the clones which are injected all have the same `id`'s.  But, even assuming there were no copies of the id, `document.getElementById` would select the template element, but I am trying to select the element in the _clone_ not in the element in the _template_

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use .querySelector() function instead.

So,

```
mtpl.getElementById('message-body').innerHTML = message.message;
```

becomes

```
mtpl.querySelector('#message-body').innerHTML = message.message;
```

And

```
mtpl.getElementById('message-user').innerHTML = `${message.client} | ${date.toString()}`;
```

becomes

```
mtpl.querySelector('#message-user').innerHTML = `${message.client} | ${date.toString()}`;
```